# df replace is not working with seperator in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a df

```
technologies= {
    'Courses':["Spark,ABCD","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","Pandas"],
    'Fee' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','30days', None,np.nan],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1000,1200,2500]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
print(df)
```

Im trying to replace column values with dict values

```
dict = {"Spark" : 'S', "PySpark" : 'P', "Hadoop": 'H', "Python" : 'P', "Pandas": 'P'}
df2=df.replace({"Courses": dict})
print(df2)
```

but the rows with seperator , is not getting replaced even though there is values present
Getting this as output

```
      Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0  Spark,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
1           P  25000   50days      2300
2           H  23000   30days      1000
3           P  24000     None      1200
4           P  26000      NaN      2500
```

but the output should be

```
      Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0      S,ABCD 22000   30days      1000
1           P  25000   50days      2300
2           H  23000   30days      1000
3           P  24000     None      1200
4           P  26000      NaN      2500
```

Comment: `regex=True` parameter in replace should help, although it will break `PySpark`.  Side note, try not to name variables after reserved keywords like `dict`

Comment: yes, as you pointed out, regex is not helping, Pyspark should be P , it is coming as PyS which is incorrect

Comment: Regex would help if you had all the compound words in the dictionary BEFORE the single words. eg change the order of pySpark and Spark. ie start with Pyspark then spark in the dictionary. Or you could simply make the keys bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably worth learning about how the regex parameter works so that you can leverage it in the future.  None the less it is possible to split on the `,` and explode so that you have one word per row.  Then you can replace and groupby the original index and join back to a comma separated string.

```
import pandas as pd
technologies= {
    'Courses':["Spark,ABCD","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","Pandas"],
    'Fee' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','30days', None,np.nan],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1000,1200,2500]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)

d = {"Spark" : 'S', "PySpark" : 'P', "Hadoop": 'H', "Python" : 'P', "Pandas": 'P'}

df.Courses = (df.Courses.str.split(',').explode().replace(d)
                        .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

Output

```
  Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0  S,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
1       P  25000   50days      2300
2       H  23000   30days      1000
3       P  24000     None      1200
4       P  26000      NaN      2500
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Ensure all the compound words are before the single words. in the dictionary `PySpark` is before `Spark`

```
d = {"PySpark" : 'P', "Spark" : 'S', "Hadoop": 'H', "Python" : 'P', "Pandas": 'P'}
df2 = df.replace({"Courses": d}, regex  = True)
print(df2)

  Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0  S,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
1       P  25000   50days      2300
2       H  23000   30days      1000
3       P  24000     None      1200
4       P  26000      NaN      2500
```

Method 2: Put the words in Boundary:

```
new_dict = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns = ['keys', 'values'])
new_dict['keys'] = '\\b' + new_dict['keys'] + '\\b'
new_dict = new_dict.set_index('keys').to_dict()['values']
df3 = df.replace({"Courses": new_dict}, regex  = True)
df3

 Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
    0  S,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
    1       P  25000   50days      2300
    2       H  23000   30days      1000
    3       P  24000     None      1200
    4       P  26000      NaN      2500
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that focuses on the column you want to change (`Courses`):

```py
dct = {"Spark" : 'S', "PySpark" : 'P', "Hadoop": 'H', "Python" : 'P', "Pandas": 'P'}
df.Courses = df.Courses.transform(
    lambda x: x.str.split(',')).transform(
    lambda x: [dct[y] if y in dct else y for y in x]).str.join(',')
```

Explanation:

- use `transform` to replace each csv string value in the column with a list
- use `transform` again, this time to replace each item in a value's list using the dictionary `dct`
- use `Series.str.join` to convert each value's list back to a csv string.

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
technologies= {
    'Courses':["Spark,ABCD","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","Pandas"],
    'Fee' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','30days', None,np.nan],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1000,1200,2500]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
print(df)

dct = {"Spark" : 'S', "PySpark" : 'P', "Hadoop": 'H', "Python" : 'P', "Pandas": 'P'}
df.Courses = df.Courses.transform(
    lambda x: x.str.split(',')).transform(
    lambda x: [dct[y] if y in dct else y for y in x]).str.join(',')
print(df)
```

Input:

```
      Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0  Spark,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
1     PySpark  25000   50days      2300
2      Hadoop  23000   30days      1000
3      Python  24000     None      1200
4      Pandas  26000      NaN      2500
```

Output:

```
  Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0  S,ABCD  22000   30days      1000
1       P  25000   50days      2300
2       H  23000   30days      1000
3       P  24000     None      1200
4       P  26000      NaN      2500
```